# Maven jetty plugin,how to do this:modify the class with out restart server

Tags: jetty, hotdeploy

Some days early,my pm asked us to use maven and jetty to development and debug the app,but i had never used them any more.
Right now , **i can't to hot deploy the app with out restart the jetty**,if i modify the app with restart the jetty every time ,i will be crazy.It waste lot of time.

So,i hope somebody can help me that,how to config this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is my jetty-maven-plugin setting. When you recompile your code, the plugin will check every 10 secs to reload the new classes.

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>7.4.5.v20110725</version>
    <configuration>
      <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

When I was using maven 2 and maven jetty plugin 7.4.5 it worked fine, but after migrating to maven 3 it didn't work anynore. 
A simple -yet not optimal solution- that i found in another forum consists in using this entry
in the configuration of the plugin:

```
<reload>manual</reload>
```

Althoug it doesn't fix the issue of automatically hot-redeploying your app if any change is detected, it allows you to restart you app by simply hitting the "enter" key.